# Passing a HTTP body from one function to another nodeJS

Tags: node.js, function, callback, request, return-value

I am using nodeJS request package and I want to return a JSON from one function to another.
Currently My Solution is:

```
var request = require('request');

function A() {
   var url = "---";
   var headers = { 'data': '---' };
   var resp = request.get({ url: url, headers:headers }, function (e, r, 
   body)
    {
      console.log(body)
    });
  return response;
}
function B() {
   data = A();
   console.log("recived data");
   console.log(data);
}
B();
```

I came across callbacks But I am pretty much confused about how to use them. I come from a python background. I am confused How can I return the body from my FuncA into FuncB. Because in this case, I am not receiving the body I want. It gives me some data like event JSON, callback JSON and much more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `async/await` and [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) like below:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

async function A() {
   var url = "---";
   var headers = { 'data': '---' };
   var resp = await request.get({ url: url, headers:headers });
  return response;
}

async function B() {
   data = await A();
   console.log("recived data");
   console.log(data);
}

B();
```

Comment: Still same output I have a problem that Function A is not returning the body So How can I return that body from A to B?

Comment: @SharvinShah the `request` package only support callback and streams i think. but here i assume that it should return promise, so one solution is that to use `request-promise` instead on `request`.  I Edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can think of a callback as a function that gets invoked when something is completed (generally speaking). In your example, the callback is this function:

```
function (e, r, 
   body)
    {
      console.log(body)
    }
```

So you need to return inside that callback because that is when you get the response from the request you make. In your example you return the response before there actually is a response to return, because the code will continue to execute and hit the return statement even if you haven't received the response yet. Also, the variable `response` does not exist.

Amir's solution above is a clean and nice way to do it. Is uses the async/await syntax which is quite new and is based on Promises. I would recommend you to look up both these concepts, but callbacks are still very common in JS (probably most common) so understanding them is important.

If you want to use callbacks in your example, try this:

```
var request = require('request');

function A(callback) {
   var url = "---";
   var headers = { 'data': '---' };
   var resp = request.get({ url: url, headers:headers }, function (e, r, 
   body)
    {
      console.log(body)
      callback(r); // Here, we send the response to the callback function
    });

}
function B() {
   A(function(data) { // this is the callback function sent to A()
       console.log("recived data");
       console.log(data);
   });
}
B();
```

(I'm not able to test this code myself at the moment though so there might be some typos.)

Edit: if you want to use the data obtained in function B you can pass it a callback like so:

```
function B(callback) {
    A(function(data) { // this is the callback function sent to A()
        console.log("recived data");
        console.log(data);
        callback(data);
   });
}
```

To use the data from function B:

```
B(function(data) {
  // do something with the data here
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to use that data from Function B for further operations how can I access it? Right Now I'm trying to access it's throwing an error.